# 4 questions about the sentence “I wish I was a doctor who could cure all the cancers.”

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, modal-verbs

I have 4 questions about this sentence below,

> “I wish I was a doctor who could cure all the cancers.”

The first is if it is a grammatically correct sentence.

The second question is if it is the best choice to use "**was**" instead of "**could be**" or "**would be**".

The third is if it is OK to say "...who **can** cure all the cancers" in this sentence.

The fourth is if I can use "**hope**" instead of "**wish**" here.

Comment: I wish our users constrained themselves to one question per, well, question. I find the question on "who can cure all the cancers" interesting though.

Comment: I wish you had asked one further question: "were" a doctor instead of "was" a doctor.

Comment: "I were", yes, I should have noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

Although plenty of native speakers would say "has" and plenty would say "had"

> She wishes she was a singer who *has* a five-octave range.
>
> She wishes she was a singer who *had* a five-octave range.

to my ear "has" sounds a little sloppy with "wishes she was".

For me, "has" doesn't go perfectly well with the counterfactual or with what we might call an "impossible dream". But "has" does work fine with a goal-oriented aspiration, but then we also swap out "was" for "to be":

> She wishes *to be* a singer who *has* a five-octave range.
>
> She wishes she was a singer who *had* a five-octave range.